# Leer Json y mostrarlo en textViews

Tags: php, android, json

Estoy rescatando dos colunmas con informacion(latitud y longitud) de una base de datos.El problema que tengo es que no puedo mostrar las columnas:latitud en un texview y la longitud en otro.
este es mi codigo:

```
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           try {
                JSONArray a = new JSONArray(response);
                String lat="",lon="";
                lat = a.getString(0);
                lon = a.getString(1);
                texto.setText(lat);
                texto1.setText(lon);

           } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

           }
        }
```

Este es el codigo en el php:

```
        while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($resultset)) {
        $arryItem["latitud"] = $arr["latitud"];
        $arryItem["longitud"] = $arr["longitud"];


        $arrRows[] = $arryItem;
        }
        echo json_encode($arrRows);
```

El `echo json_encode($arrRows);` me da lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como tendria que ser para que la latitud lo tenga en `texto.setText(lat);` y la longitud lo tenga en   `texto1.setText(lon);`

Comment: trendras que explicarte algo mejor, para poder ayudarte, ¿que error te da? y que quieres hacer exactamente , solo mostrar el primer valor en un textView, fijate que lo que es a a es un objeto de lat y lon, debuguea y mira el valor que tiene a

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el posible problema esta que estas devolviendo un **JSONArray** y estas intentando leer como si fuera otra estructura de datos. Para obtener los datos de un array puedes intentar con el siguiente código.

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
           try {
                JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
                String lat="",lon="";
                lat = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0).toString();
                lon = jsonarray.getJSONObject(1).toString();
                texto.setText(lat);
                texto1.setText(lon);

           } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

           }
        }
```